# 'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I tried to compile [some project](https://github.com/yevgeniy-logachev/QtAdMobApp/tree/master/QMLApp) for iOS and got the following compiler errors:

```
../../../libs/QT6.4/iOs/include/QtCore/qfile.h:31:58: error: 'path' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 13.0
inline QString fromFilesystemPath(const std::filesystem::path &path)
```

in the following code:

```
inline QString fromFilesystemPath(const std::filesystem::path &path)
```

and the following error:

```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer /SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem:902:24: note: 'path' has  been explicitly marked unavailable here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
                   ^
```

in the following code:

```
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS path {
template <class _SourceOrIter, class _Tp = path&>
using _EnableIfPathable =
  typename enable_if<__is_pathable<_SourceOrIter>::value, _Tp>::type;
```

what project settings should I change to make this compile?

my XCode version 13.2

Comment: Sounds like maybe your project is configured to target an older iOS version prior to 13.0

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, it is `ios:QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` in QT project `pro` file.

Comment: Well, then there is your answer. You can't use `std::filesystem::path` in code that targets iOS versions prior to 13.0.